# Windows server 2008 hours lasting restart loop then runs OK for months

Tags: windows-server-2008

My windows server 2008 (PDC) is providing AD+DNS+DHCP+RADIUS services for my network with about 100 PCs.

It runs just fine for MONTHS, only when i need to restart him (updates or other reason) strange things happen. It is configures not to reboot itself on BSOD (i wanted to find out what's wrong) but things look like this.

Server powers off, then i see BIOS boot screen, then OS selector screen,  then Windows Server logo, (now hdd led is  flashing and then stops) after that i just see BIOS boot screen again. This can loop for 45-60 minutes but eventualy server starts (when server starts HDD led I mentioned earlier flashes more intense and don't stop till about 15 minutes after server is fully ON). Only thing in event log is "Server shutdown at XX:YY was unexpected" and it is there only once despite server was rebooting itself maybe 20 times.... When it finally starts there is no problem whatsoever for month, until I need to restart him again due to updates...

So i usually restart him about 2:00 AM so he will kick in during time everyone sleeps. But this time he did't kick in, I restarted him via RDP and he probably hang (or I "finally" got BSOD and he actually obeyed and did't restart itself...), so i'm going to work early morning to fix this, at this time I have no idea what my poor server is doing... But i guess this hang is not related to issue because to this day server has recovered everytime I rebooted it. Any idea what can cause this??? I am desperate, because if i'm gona need to put up a new server and move whole AD there... I will spend a LOT of time on it which I don't have...

Comment: What's the underlying hardware that this server is comprised of?

Comment: Asus M4A78T-E (latest BIOS), ADM Phenom II X4 955, 8GB 1333 ECC DDR3, 4x WD Caviar 500GB, 2x WD Caviar 1TB (on internal SATA RAID controller), 500W Fortron PSU, Realtek 8168 PCI-E NIC, Atheros AR8121 onboard NIC, I guess that's it

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by clearing CMOS and setting up BIOS again (using the same settings). BIOS was previously flashed few times but CMOS was never cleared. Since I considered this issue a driver/software fault, i never thought about it...